# Microsoft Office Add In - How to detect a built in button on the ribbon is clicked (i.e. bold clicked)?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, ribbonx, excel-web-addins

I'm currently trying to develop an add in for Microsoft Excel and have spent a lot of time going through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office?view=common-js-preview to learn what is available through the API. However, I cannot figure out how to detect when a button on the top ribbon (for example the bold button) is pressed by the user. Any help would be appreciated!

Most of the available documentation gives methods for detecting custom buttons that are pressed, but not already built in buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The Office JavaScript API (`OfficeJS`) library doesn't provide anything for that. Consider creating a COM based add-in if you need to repurpose built-in ribbon controls. Office web add-ins are still limited in their functionality if we compare them with COM add-ins. But you can suggest or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.